# CommandLineTools folder displayed in Finder but not in CLI OS 10.9.4

Tags: macos, mac, command-line, filesystems, xcode

The finder browser shows CommandLineTools, `xcode-select --print-path` also shows the path, `/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/` but I cannot get to it using `cd` and `ls` doesn't show it inside of the `/Developer/` folder.

Screenshot:
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you did `cd Library` your are in your home (`/Users/your-username/Library`). If you type the following you will get into that directory:

```
cd /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/
```

The point is that if your are in `~` and your type `cd Library` you will enter into `~/Library`. From the same start point, if you type `cd /Library` you will enter into `/Library`.